# Power BI: Make a Table Visualization display all observations of a dataset

Tags: powerbi

I've noticed that If you have a table in the Data Viewer in Power BI desktop such as this:

[image]

Then, if you insert the same table in a Table Visualization, the table will only display distinct values of the categories:

[image]

How can you set up a Table Visualization so that the data is displayed as it is in the Data Viewer where *all* observations are displayed?

Comment: Maybe add an index column to the table and include that in the visual too?

Comment: @Alexis Olson That's a nice work-around! But it still bothers me that (if) there isn't some built-in option to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Power Bi Desktop currently does not have an option to display *all* observations in the Table Visualization(Oct 2018).  I am optimistic the Power Bi team will correct this problem in a future release.  If you feel strongly about this feature, please go to the [Power Bi improvement Idea post](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/13735062-display-tabular-data-as-is-without-aggregation) and add your vote.

I'm answering this question to perhaps help others who come here looking for a work around until it gets implemented.

There is currently one work around that I know of:  Add an index column to the data table, add this column to your table visualization, then shrink the column width of the index to hide the data.  This is not a desirable work around, but might get you a solution in a pinch until the feature is implemented.

So for your example, to add an index column to your table, go to Edit Queries -> Add Column -> Index Column -> From 1

[image: Add Index Column]

Then - back to your report, add the Index column to the Table Visualization and make sure you select Don't Summarize for the Index Column values tab pull down.

[image: dont summarize]

Once the index column is added to your table, and you sort by the index your table visualization should look like the following:

[image]

The last step is to hide the index column by shrinking the column width of the index column.  Before you do this, you need to turn off word wrap for the columns and the values.  Go to the paint roller and in Column Header and Values make sure you turn word wrap off:

[image: word wrap off]

then your final table will look like the following with all of the values required.  The grey box is my mouse over the shrunk index column and wont show up for you unless you mouse over that area:

[image]